# Alamofire URLRequestConvertible global headers

Tags: swift, http-headers, alamofire

Recently, I replace my old Alamofire requests with URLRequestConvertible protocol, for example, the country route is something like this:

```
enum CountryRoute: URLRequestConvertible {

    case countries

    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .countries : return Path.Common.countries.rawValue
        }
    }

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .get
    }

    public var headers: HTTPHeaders {
        return ["X-Mode" : "Light"]
    }

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = try "example.com".asURL()
        var request = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
        request.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        request.headers = headers
        request.timeoutInterval = TimeInterval(10*1000)
        return try URLEncoding.default.encode(request,with: nil)
    }
}
```

and final the request is like this:

```
shared.session.request(convertible).validate().responseData { (response) in   
    // Do something    
}
```

as I understand for each route we set headers, but what if we have global headers like **"Content-Type"** or **"Accept-Language"** or even **Bearer Token**?

Are there any ways to prevent add repetitious headers and add them globally? or we have to add these headers to each route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire already generates some headers for the whole session when you using the default `Session`:

```
let session = Session.default
```

or the `AF` reference (which uses the default `Session` behind the scenes)

Those default headers include **Accept-Encoding**, **Accept-Language** and **User-Agent**. As for **Content-Type** header, `URLEncoding` or `JSONEncoding` are responsible for setting the correct values. (`JSONParameterEncoder` or `URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder` when you passing `Encodable` types as parameters)

However, you can override those headers by creating a new `Session` using your own `URLSessionConfiguration`:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default // Alamofire's default URLSessionConfiguration
configuration.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
let session = Session(configuration: configuration)
```

Note: For Bearer token, there is a mechanism which requires the implementation of `RequestInterceptor` protocol in order to intercept every request and append the correct header. Using the same protocol you can also provide a refresh token functionality.